# Rust .sh installer require permission to write to .bashrc

Tags: bash, macos, rust

I was trying to install Rust on my Mac with the command

```
sudo curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
```

When I selected the default option that is supposed to edit `.bashrc`, I got the error

> could not amend shell profile: '/Users/andreyshedko/.bashrc': could not write rcfile file: '/Users/andreyshedko/.bashrc': Permission denied (os error 13)

The command already has sudo permission, what else is missing?

Comment: **Why** are you using sudo? It's not required or recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sh` wasn't not executed with `sudo`, only `curl` (unnecessarily so) was. You probably meant to use

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sudo sh
```

but executing unknown code with root privileges seems like a horrible idea. (It's also not obvious why a process run under your user id would fail to have permission to write to your own `.bashrc` file.)

Comment: And sudo isn't even required for this.

Comment: Please look for duplicate questions and answers before posting an answer.

Comment: @Shepmaster, the answer from the link above has helped.